# Webservice - client service instantiation

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Do you know how costly is to create a webservice client service instance ?

```
 JavaWebService service = new JavaWebService();
 SomePort port = service.getJavaWebServicePort();
```

Creating the service once and after that reusing same port in a multi threaded  environment (webapp) is not dangerous ?

Read that the port getPort and port itself is not thread safe but also creating each time a service it might be problematic if it is a costly operation.

Any idea ?

THanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the JAX-WS reference implementation (Metro), the creation of the `JavaWebService` is inexpensive (in our generated clients, we tend to find this takes around 20ms).

The first creation of `SomePort` is quite expensive (circa 200ms for us); subsequent calls to `getSomePort()` on the same `JavaWebService` instance are substantially quicker (circa 3ms for us).

So, an implementation that creates a `JavaWebService` every time it needs to get a `SomePort` will carry a degree of expense. In short, the answer to the question is "Quite costly".

However, even though the methods on `SomePort` are not thread safe, the methods on `JavaWebService` are. So, the sensible usage pattern (at least with Metro - thread-safety is implementation specific due to a somewhat lacking specification) is to reuse `JavaWebService` as you will only incur the expensive `getSomePort()` call once.

**Update**

This agrees with two posts by Andreas Leow, an employee from Oracle Germany, one of the posters in the thread referenced by @PapaLazarou in the comment below, who wrote regarding the `Service` object,

> You can create just one single static `Service` instance per WSDL: any single `Service` object is fully thread-safe and can be shared by as many concurrent threads as you like.

and about the usage of ports,

> While I am almost 100% certain that CXF JAX-WS Ports are thread-safe, Metro's `Port` objects definitely are *not* thread-safe.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? So far all I can find are posts that the returned ports are not thread-safe and CXF's page saying that "clients" (I assume they mean ports) are not thread-safe. What I'm seeking is some *official* statement that Metro services (not ports) are thread-safe, specifically that calls to `getPort` return separate instances.

Comment: I found a number of post by the Metro devs that indicated this but have struggled to locate them again. The only post I've managed to locate recently is [this](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAX-WS-clients-td5709817.html) one. FYI, my independent concurrent tests also indicated this to be the case.

Comment: According to the CXF documentation (http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAX-WSclientproxiesthreadsafe?) "CXF proxies are thread safe for MANY use cases." See the documentation for further explanations.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jax-ws, then you cannot share a port across threads (they are not thread-safe).  if you are concerned about the overhead of creating a port (and have measured it and confirmed that it is a bottleneck in your application), then you could create a connection pool of ports.

Comment: I read that they are not thread safe on cxf site,they provide a thread safe getPort...but i use MEtro stack JaxWS.So creating the service might be a heavy operation ? (will start doing some tests but did not wanted to reinvent the wheel)